# Table View like in Instagram app

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, tableview, instagram

In Instagram app when you add new photo you can see this table:

[image]

How can i create it? Any ideas

Comment: if you already have this question posted an hour ago....why did you post it again??

Comment: nobody answered and nobody understanded me in that question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Eugene its a `group table` with multiple sections. If you don't know how to create group table then have a look at this tutorial - http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-uitableview-tutorial-grouped-table/

Answer (score 2):

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style
```

here you can specify `UITableViewStyleGrouped` as the style to get the grouped tableview you see..

**Table view datasource**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

here you should return the no..of section in the table (above image has 2 sections ..)

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

the above method is used to specify the title for the section..in the above image(first section does not have a title...return "**Sharing**" for second)

Rest is done in :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

**here you can provide a custom text for the cell...change its font...show accessory in the cells..add images to the cell..**